# Duplex Client Server Interaction

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to create a client-server model that can send and recieve updates. I have been reading up on WCF to do this. However I continually run into issues with the `DuplexClientBase`/`DuplexChannelFactory` needing a client at the point of construction. I am looking for insight into whether or not I am using WCF correctly and how to better go about my goal.

The server side is easy as you get the client channel through `OperationContext.Current`. However the client side can't directly get a channel due to the channel needing the client...? So if the client wants to send a message to the server it can't as it's all encapsulated in the `DuplexClientBase`.

Code to try and clear up my point:

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IClient))]
public interface IServer
{
    // The server can get and manage a channel through
    // OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IClient>()
    // This is perfect as the server can directly interact with
    // the client
    [OperationContract]
    void Register();

    [OperationContract]
    void Greet();
}

public class ServerProxy : DuplexClientBase<IServer>
{
    // In order for the client to recieve messages from the Server
    // This class extends DuplexClientBase, however the constructors
    // For DuplexClientBase require an instance context (A client)
    public ServerProxy(Client client, Binding binding, EndpointAddress address)
        : base(new InstanceContext(client), binding, address) {}

    public void Register()
    {
        Channel.Register();
    }
}

public class Client : IClient
{
    // The client can now receive messages from the server but how is it
    // meant to send messages to the server? So if the client wanted
    // to "greet" the server it can't as that has to be done through
    // "ServerProxy"
}
```

I can see two ways to go about this but I am not comfortable enough with WCF to say if either approach is right.

1. The Server could be split into two services, one not having a callback contract. This would allow the Client to extend `ClientBase` and at least access some functions of the server. But then the client can't "greet" AND be "registered" by the server.
2. Give the client the `ServerProxy`? But the cyclic nature enclines me to believe this isn't a good idea.